# Replace string containing quotes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe which is a list of dictionaries. 
Eg:

```
[{'attr': 'color', 'value': 'BLUE'}]
```

The issue is 'attr' and 'value' are not required, and I want the format in all rows to change to :

```
[{'color' : 'BLUE'}]
```

pandas str.replace is not working since 'attr' and 'value' are contained within quotes, and I am unable to write a suitable regex that completely removes 'attr' and 'value' but keeps the quotes over color and BlUE.

What can be a pythonic way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[{'attr': 'color', 'value': 'BLUE'}]]})
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: [dict([i.values()]) for i in x])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                       A
0  [{'color': 'BLUE'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[{'attr': 'color', 'value': 'BLUE'}]]})
df['col'].apply(lambda x: {elt['attr']: elt['value'] for elt in x})
```